# .htaccess rewrite hidden parameter and keep files the same

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with .htaccess using apache.

I want be able to type in a URL like this:

```
example.com/bob
```

and I want to rewrite the URL as

```
example.com/index.php?c=bob
```

I also don't want it to affect real files and to load them normally

```
example.com/account.php
```

In addition to all of this, I want to rewrite real files without the .php

```
example.com/account
```

So far I've been focusing on the index.php?c=bob task. I have this so far in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|account\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

The work heavy solution I thought of is to list all of my files in line 1 above, I am looking for a more efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It runs the example.com/bob correctly. I tried example.com/account.php and it acted as if 'account.php' is an input like 'bob'

Comment: @Jake, could you please do let me know if you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: I got the top comment mixed up and updated it. I don't have anything else in my .htaccess file. although example.com is a subdomain, sub.example.com

Comment: @Jake, ok so you mean these rules are working fine but you want to redirect request to a new sub domain name? If I am not wrong here that wasn't mentioned in question.

Comment: It didn't come to mind for the question, just in case it matters I mentioned that this was all within a subdomain. To clarify I want to stay in the same subdomain always sub.example.com

Comment: Your last answer update solved the problem it is working great now. Thank you